# DFA Minimization

Tags: finite-automata

I am currently in a class that deals with DFA's and their minimization. However I believe I have reached a DFA where the method of minimization we were taught doesn't work.

I have the following DFA (in JFLAP)

[image]

Using the method given in class I do the following see if their are any non dissimilar states and if so collapse them together.

```
 | q0  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5 
-------------------------
a| q1  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  
b| q3  q2  q5  q4  q5  q5
```

However there are no states where both a and b go to the same state, therefore no collapse states.

However when doing it in JFLAP it gives the following

[image]

The only way I can see you getting what JFLAP does is just thinking and having to realize bother q1 and q3 can be joined as well as q2 and q4.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How is this a DFA given that state initial state q0 has two transitions for an input symbol a?

Comment: The a near q3 is going from q3 to q3.

Comment: @DavidRicherby What is the JFLAP minimization doing that the other method is just missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method of DFA minimization is incorrect. You start with assuming all states to be different and merge the indistinguishable ones, this may not give the correct minimization. The correct way is to assume all to be same states and  separate those which are distinguishable. Look at [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/520-S08/handouts/Lec7.pdf) for exact algorithm.

Comment: Huh ok I'll go back and look at it again. I'm probably making some mistake as i see a lot of similarities to the way the class explained it. Thanks for the information.